# How to link to a non-existing Org-mode file and then create it?

Tags: org-mode

I would like to use Org-mode as a local wiki, and I have just discovered how to link Org-mode files (Cf. http://orgmode.org/manual/External-links.html#External-links).

Now I'd like to link a non-existing Org-mode and when running some command on the link of clicking it, opening it that new Org-mode file in a buffer – similar to creating a new wiki page.

How to achieve this?  Is there some built-in method in Org-mode?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just do it? Create a link, e.g.

```
[[file:./newfile.org][newfile]]
```

Click on it(*) and emacs creates a new buffer. Then, e.g.,

```
C-x C-s
```

to save it.

Being emacs, we probably may have some automatic saving solution, but I do not immediately know how.

(*) EDIT: or move the cursor over the link and hit RET (return)

Comment: This also works for links to headlines not existing yet (will ask if you want to create the headline when following the link).

Comment: Can this be done without using a mouse?

Comment: @PeterJankuliak yes move the cursor over the link and hit RET (return)